# Is there any way to set Date in DatePickerFragment in Android(Xamarin)

Tags: android, datepicker, xamarin.android, android-datepicker

I am making one Dialog. In the Initial state the DatePickerFragment show the current date. and I set that date to my TextView. it's working fine.

The below is the code :

**DatePickerFragment class**

```
public class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment,
                                  DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
    {
        public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

        // Initialize this value to prevent NullReferenceExceptions.
        Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

        public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
        {
            DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
            frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;

            return frag;
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                           this,
                                                           currently.Year,
                                                           currently.Month - 1,
                                                           currently.Day);
            return dialog;
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);

            _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);

        }
    }
```

on Activity use this way inside my dialog.

```
txt_selectDate = dialog.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_selectDate);
                        DateTime cuurently = DateTime.Now;
                        txt_selectDate.Text = cuurently.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        dialog.Show();

                        var select_date = dialog.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.select_date);
                        select_date.Click += SelectDate_Click;
```

and Create click method like this

```
void SelectDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DatePickerFragment frag = DatePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate (DateTime time)
                    {
                        var pickupDate = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        txt_selectDate.Text = time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    });

                frag.Show(context.FragmentManager, DatePickerFragment.TAG);
            }
```

## Problem :

Now when i again click to pickup new Date the `DatePickerFragment` show the Current date not the previous selected Date. So is there any way I can set the Previous date to `DatePickerFragment`?

Any Help be Appreciated.

**Update :**

[image]

After adding param it will give this response.

Comment: I have done this in native android may be it'll help. You can get the existing date right?

Comment: @Raghavendra yes I want to set existing date .

Comment: No I have asked are u saving the existing date anywhere?

Comment: Yes in the `TextView` field. you can see in my code click method this line `txt_selectDate.Text = time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); `

Comment: When u load the dialog can u pass the date which is set to textview in the constructor. And use updateDate method of DatePickerDialog to set existing date. Make a try and let me know

Comment: @Raghavendra can you elaborate more ?

Comment: I don't know xamarin much but let me give a try. You have NewInstance method in DatePickerFragment class add one more param say, existing_date. Before setting the DateTime currently = DateTime.Now; Create a DateTime Object with date u have and set that. Can I post an answer but I'm sure some mistakes would be there I'll just use your code:)

Comment: @Raghavendra I try many way but nothing is work i pass `DateTime` as param but not resolve that.

Comment: Did u solve the issue?

Comment: @Raghavendra No the issue is still.

Comment: Can u do the changes which I'll post in comments one by one let's see if it works

Comment: Just do it for testing, Change the NewInstance definition to DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)

Comment: @Raghavendra I try as you suggest by passing param as argument but `DatePickerFragment` can't accept it. And also try to cast the param with `DateTime` but also that not work.

Comment: okay dude then I don't have xamarin studio setup with me now to test and post a solution. If u solve the issue post as ur soln.

Comment: @Raghavendra after try to add param as you suggest what i have to change in my `DatePickerFragment`.

Comment: In OnCreateDialog just change DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                           this,
                                                           year,
                                                           monthOfYear,
                                                           dayOfMonth); and check whether its changing the value

Comment: @Raghavendra if i use this then the `Year` is not work.

Comment: Not work means. Does it give errors?

Comment: @Raghavendra see my update ?

Comment: okay can u do this create 1 more method, public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance()

Comment: without arguments and keep it as a  blank method

Comment: Oops u need to pass params!! in the old method where it was showing error change like this DatePickerFragment.NewInstance(delegate (DateTime time), 2016,11,11) and try

Comment: @Raghavendra can you post full answer I can't understand you.

Comment: Can u check the change here https://bitbucket.org/snippets/raghavendrav/yyK5K and let me know

Comment: @Raghavendra it will give error unexpected opening brace `{` before `2016` and  `)` after `11`.

Comment: Okay, dude I have tried it didn't work.

Comment: @Raghavendra Thanks for your support and time. I will start bounty shortly on this question.

Comment: I think you can do one more read how to pass arguments to fragment from activity. Send the existing date to the fragment

Comment: @Raghavendra the problem was solve you can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `DatePickerFragment` I use `DatePickerDialog` with following way which was solve my problem.

Display DatePicker like this way

```
ddtime = new DatePickerDialog(context, OnDateSet, DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month - 1,
                                                     DateTime.Today.Day
                                                             );

                            ddtime.DatePicker.DateTime = selected_Date;
                            ddtime.SetTitle("");
                            ddtime.Show();
```

and it's method `OnDataSet` like this way

```
async void OnDateSet(object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs e)
            {
                default_date = e.Date.Year + "/" + e.Date.Month + "/" + e.Date.Day;
                txt_selectDate.Text = e.Date.Day + "/" + e.Date.Month + "/" + e.Date.Year;
                selected_Date = e.Date;
            }
```

and finally my `selected_Date` is set in datePicker like below way

```
ddtime.DatePicker.DateTime = selected_Date;
```